# Visual studio 2013 regex search : looking for all strings of the form "if (something > 0)" + variations

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, full-text-search

I am using visual studio 2013 and working with quite a big c++/c# library. In it, I am looking for all occurences of strings of the form `ifXPOXvarXsymXzeroXPC` where :

- `X` is any string composed only with spaces (the empty caracter, zero space, is also allowed)
- `PO` and `PC` are either both empty or respectively equal to `(` and `)`
- `var` is any (c++ or c# kosher) variable name
- `sym` is any operator equal to `>`, `<`, `<=` or `>=`
- `zero` is equal to `0`, `0.` or `0.0`

Example of strings I want to catch :

```
if    avar  <=   0.
if(anothervar>0)
if yetanothervar>  0
if ( lastvar >= 0.0 )
```

*etc*...

I tried `if \s*\(\s*\w+ > 0\.?\0?\s*\)\s*`and `if \s*\(\s*\w+\s*>\s*0\.?\0?\s*\)\s*` without success as I remarked each time in the results lists that I did not get everything. I would btw really like to stick to visual studio 2013's regex.

Ideally, I would also like to find string where `PO` could be composed with more than one opening parenthesis, in which I omit `PC`, to be able to find strings of the form `if (((x > 0)` where the algebraic condition looked for belongs to a combo of many "algebraic comparisions" or other comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex you can leverage here:

```
(?m)^if\s*\(?\s*\w+\s*[<>]=?\s*0\.?0?\s*\)?
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eif%5cs*%5c(%3f%5cs*%5cw%2b%5cs*%5b%3c%3e%5d%3d%3f%5cs*0%5c.%3f0%3f%5cs*%5c)%3f&i=if++++avar++%3c%3d+++0.%0d%0aif(anothervar%3e0)%0d%0aif+yetanothervar%3e++0%0d%0aif+(+lastvar+%3e%3d+0.0+)&o=m)

Note the use of the multiline mode that forces `^` match the beginning of the line. If `if` is not at the very start of the line, replace `^` with `\b`.

[image]

Comment: And thanks for the demo pointing to a nice tool for someone having never used regexes before.

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for checking what is going on with your .NET regex. But regexstorm is a good online regex tester with sharing capabilities that is why I am using it. Also, regexhero.net is great.

Comment: Please consider also upvoting the answer if it proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should do the trick:

**^if\s*(*\s*\w+\s*[!=<>&|]+\s*0.?0?\s*)*\s***

Tested [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eif%5cs*%5c(*%5cs*%5cw%2b%5cs*%5b!%3d%3c%3e%26%7c%5d%2b%5cs*0%5c.%3f0%3f%5cs*%5c)*%5cs*&i=if++++avar++%3c%3d+++0.%0d%0aif(anothervar%3e0)%0d%0aif+yetanothervar%3e++0%0d%0aif+(+lastvar+%3e%3d+0.0+)&o=m)

Note: The regex *[!=<>&|]* is used to match any relational operator or logical operator.